# Why must a function, declared as friend in Class A, be defined as a public function in Class B?

Tags: c++, class, friend

Class A is a container for Class B instances.

File A.h:

```
#include "B.h"

Class A
{   public:
    unique_ptr<B>                       getInstanceOfB();

    private:
    unique_ptr<map<int, shared_ptr<B>>> uptr_BInstancesMap;
    map<string, int>                    map__BUniqueValues;

    friend int                          B::getValueIndex( const string );
};
```

File B.h:

```
Class B
{   public:
    unique_ptr<B>                       returnInstanceOfB();
//  int                                 getValueIndex( const string );  // Compiles fine

    private:
    int                                 int__ValueIndex;
    int                                 getValueIndex( const string );  // "error: 'int B::getValueIndex(std::string)' is private"
}
```

There may be upwards of 100,000 instances of B stored in the instance of A, but there will be far fewer unique values represented by those instances of B.
So the idea is to store the unique values in the instance of A and store the index to its (shared) value in each instance of B.
Seems like a reasonable scenario for a friend function.

getValueIndex() is for use *within* Class B however; it shouldn't be public.
Would someone explain (perhaps with a dangerous example) why the friend function definition can't be private?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Poor wording.  Would "Class A is a container for Class B" be more accurate?

Comment: Much better. I'll delete my comment now.

Comment: Declaring `friend int B::getValueIndex(const string);` in class A gives it access to class A's private/protected members, not the other way around.

Comment: Dmitri, that's exactly what I want.  B::getValueIndex will manipulate A::map__BUniqueValues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "circularity" here.

friend in A means that the declared function can access A private parts.

But to access that declaration, it has to be accessible to A itself, hence B must have A as a friend.

I understand your wish of "purity", but C++ is all but an "pure" language. If A and B are closely related and you are responsible for both of them, instead of go crazy with single declarations, just make them each other friends.

No one -outside of them- can do anything dangerous, and you are already in you own "danger zone", you already know about... so why the complication?

Comment: Adding "friend class A" to class B did the trick!  I don't yet understand "to access that declaration, it has to be accessible to A itself", but this is my guess: The friend function declaration in class A tells the compiler that A wants to give B::getValueIndex() access to its private members, but the compiler refuses because B::getValueIndex() is private and A is not allowed to even know it's there.  Adding "friend class A" to class B grants A access to B's private members - including B::getValueIndex() - so the compiler can now give that function access to A's private members.

Comment: Exactly: private over private required double "friend with benefits" ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My take on it:

Private methods should be changeable at will, with no impact outside of the class. If you make a private method of `B` a friend of `A`, that private method's signature signature cannot be changed w/o changing `A`.

Comment: Arkadiy: but if you make a change to (e.g. rename) a private member of A, you'd have to change the friend function in B.  It seems to me that using friend functions implicitly acknowledges the need to change both classes.

Comment: No one can be "friend" of someone without the other wants it

Comment: When B is a friend of A, you acknowledge that B has to change when A's private members are changed. But - not the other way around. A has no knowledge about B's private members.

Comment: Arkadiy: My intent is that B::getValueIndex() will access private members of both A and B.  There's no intent that A will have access to anything in B.  But Dmitri thought the same thing so there must be something in my code that suggests A will be trying to access B.  Is it the lack of a reference to an instance of A in the function signature?

Comment: If you make the friend function private, then A, by definition, knows about one private function of B (the one cited in the friend declaration). I think that C++ standard writers considered this undesirable, so friend function has to be public. It's a pretty weak justification, but best I could think of for now.

Comment: Hmm.  If we design A to have private members, but the friend function in B must be public, then isn't the friend function basically allowing public access to some of A's private members?  Emilio's answer allows the friend function to be private, although I'm still struggling to see why class A needs to access the friend declaration.